# React Typescript onSubmit type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm having issues around creating an onSubmit function and giving it a type.

On the very first line where you'd normally set a type for the function, no matter what I seem to give even any or unknown I'm seeing an error.

The error suggests I can't put type of `any` on the type of

```
(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>, data: FormProps) => void
```

But even if I do give it this exact suggested type I still return an error.

```
const onSubmitHandler = (e: any, setVerificationId: any, setVerificationToken: any) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setUserData({
            platform: '',
            name: {
                givenNames: givenNames ? givenNames : memberDetails.memberNameDetails.givenNames,
                surname: surname ? surname : memberDetails.memberNameDetails.lastName
            },
            email: email,
            dob: formattedDateOfBirth,
            currentAddress: {
                line1: streetNameInformation,
                postCode: postCode,
                suburb: suburb,
                state: state,
                country: country,
            }})

        aService.postVerificationRegister(userData)
            .then(response => {
                setVerificationId(response.verificationId)
                setVerificationToken(response.verificationToken)
            })
            .catch((e) => console.error("There was an error getting a verification token", e))
}
```

```
<Form id="not-the-form" role="form" action="/" onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
```

Any help would be appreicated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The submit handler function in React could be like the below in terms of type:

```
import { FormEvent } from "react";

function onSumbitHandler(e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
  // ...
}
```

```js
<form onSubmit={onSumbitHandler}></form>
```

[image]

If your submit handler function needs other type of parameters, you can do it this way using an arrow function:

```
<form
  onSubmit={(e) =>
    onSubmitHandler(e, setVerificationId, setVerificationToken)
  }
></form>
```

Comment: SILLY ME. Yes it does work to just pass in the (e) maybe I was focused on the wrong thing. Regardless thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This should be a [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)

Comment: Thanks - that helps as far as typing the `e` my issue is the type of the actual function.

const onSubmitHandler = (e: any, setVerificationId: any, setVerificationToken: any): THIS_TYPE_HERE  => {}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just pulled the semantic-ui-react library and tested. The following works with typescript (assuming you're using the 2nd argument).

```
import React from "react";
import { Form, FormProps } from "semantic-ui-react";

const Component = () => {
  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>, data: FormProps) => {/* your code */};
  return (
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
  );
};
```

If you're not using the data argument then you'd have

```
  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => { /* your code */};
```

The return type that you're thinking typescript is complaining about is automatically determined to be "void" by typescript because the function is not returning any value.

**Edit:** Your question appears to have changed, and your handler now has 3 arguments. Neither the html `<form/>` element or the semantic-ui-react `<Form/>` onSubmit function signatures match what you're passing. It sounds like you're wanting to pass custom arguments to your handler. In which case you'd need to have a higher order function.

```
const onSubmitHandler = (setVerificationId: type, setVerificationToken: type) = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => { /* your code */}

// calling code
<Form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler(setVerificationId, setVerificationToken)}>
```